# Broken master page

Tags: 2013, master-page

I tried making an edit to the master page HTML file and I guess I made a mistake. I uploaded the HTML file to the master page gallery and now I can't access any part of the SharePoint site. Whenever I try to load any part of the site it says

> "An error occurred during translation of your HTML master page.  For
>   more information, please navigate to the master page by clicking the
>   preview button in the Master Page Gallery or directly typing its URL."

I can't use PowerShell because we aren't allowed to run scripts on these systems. Is there any way to change the master page to a different one so that I can upload a non-broken version of my master page?

Comment: If you do not apply your customer page to the system pages then navigate to the your ChangeMasterPage url `siteurl/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx` and change

Comment: You can also change the master page from the SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I wasn't using Sharepoint designer for the website. Can I add the website to sharepoint designer now?

Comment: See my answer and comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem in the simplest way I could:

I just mapped a network drive to `{mySite}/_catalogs/masterpage` and uploaded a working HTML file to replace the corrupted master page.

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Comment: I would if I could. It doesn't let me accept my own answers until 2 days after I post them.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not apply your customer page to the system pages then navigate to your ChangeMasterPage URL `siteurl/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx` and change.

or

You can open the site from the SharePoint designer.

- Go to All Files -> _catalogs -> masterpage.
- Select the working master page like default `oslo` or `seattle`.
- Right click the .master file and select "Set as a custom master page".

Comment: You can install the SharePoint designer onto your local machine and open from that tool